# Why is Code Signing Identity not listing my certificate?

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 4 and am trying to sign my first Mac OS X application.  When I go to `Project -> Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity`, it will list "Don't Sign", "Automatic Profile Selector", and "Other".  Under "Automatic Profile Selector" it lists "3rd Party Mac Developer Application".  When I build it fails and says `Code Sign error:

> The identity '3rd Party Mac Developer Application' doesn't match any
>   valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Earlier, in `Organizer -> Provisiong Profiles`, I did a refresh.  It setup two certificates in  `Device -> Developer Profile`.  Nothing appears in Provisioning Profiles.  The two certificates it shows in Developer Profile exist in my keychain as valid.  I see no expired certificates even when I "show expired".

The certificates it has in Developer Profile match what's in the keychain:

> 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer:  MyCompany, LLC
>
> Mac Developer: My Name (SOMECODE)

I don't see these in the Code Signing Identity list, though.  I even tried entering in the first one in Other, but it said it could not find it.

I have no need for entitlements, so I don't have a profile setup.  And I am the company admin.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this turned out to be a lot simpler than I had imagined.

After I refresh and download the certs:

1) Click on My Mac under devices.  And click "Add to Portal".  This will download the Mac Team Provisioning Wildcard Profile

2) Create an App ID for my app (necessary for sandboxing/entitlements), through the website

3) Add a new Developer Provisioning Profile for this App ID, through the website

4) Go to Organizer and refresh.

Everything appears now.

---

But, I realize that for a Mac App w/ no sandboxing/entitlements, I really didn't need to do this.  I could have got away with just creating the Production Provisioning Profile, since it does not require a registered device.